# What's the difference between PyInstaller and auto-py-to-exe?

Tags: pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I am developing a small app for macOS that I want to convert as an executable. For this I use `auto-py-to-exe`. I always thought it's just a GUI for `PyInstaller`, but [this article](https://medium.com/@asusrishabh/convert-python-program-to-exe-c773345716df) states, that "Another advantage is that Auto-py-to-exe creates an executable file that is a built version of the source code rather than the original source code". I always thought the results of these both tools should be the same, shouldn't they?

`auto-py-to-exe` also gives you the `PyInstaller` command-line prompt. If I execute this, I get the three outputs (folders `build` and `dist` and the `.spec` file). `auto-py-to-exe` only gives one folder as output, which I thought it should be the same then the `dist` folder. Is that true? If `auto-py-to-exe` uses `PyInstaller` shouldn't there also be a `build` folder and a `.spec` file?

I am a bit confused and I don't find a proper manual for `auto-py-to-exe` explaining this. Maybe somebody can shed some light here :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

auto-py-to-exe is just a UI layer on top of PyInstaller - it calls PyInstaller internally.

Directly from auto-py-to-exe's README.md

> A .py to .exe converter using a simple graphical interface and [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) in Python.

auto-py-to-exe offers the following on top of PyInstaller:

- A UI to use PyInstaller
- Basic validation on PyInstaller inputs (like paths and .ico file types)
- Builds your script in a temporary directory so there is no need for manual cleanup
- PyInstaller and Python version checks (where some versions can be incompatible)
- Minor default differences where issues typically occur (at the moment we just change the recursion limit)
- Some non-English language support

*Disclosure: I am the creator of auto-py-to-exe*

Answer (score -3):

Both PyInstaller and auto-py-to-exe are tools used to convert Python scripts into standalone executable files, but they have different features, functionalities, and levels of user-friendliness.

**PyInstaller:**

- Features: PyInstaller is a well-established and widely-used tool that
  can package Python scripts along with their dependencies into a
  single executable file for various platforms (Windows, macOS, Linux).
- Flexibility: It offers more customization options and supports more
  advanced features, making it suitable for complex projects with
  unique requirements.
- Command-Line Interface: PyInstaller is primarily operated through the
  command-line interface (CLI). Users need to provide configuration
  options and parameters via command-line arguments.
- Ease of Use: While powerful, PyInstaller might have a steeper
  learning curve for newcomers due to its extensive options and
  command-line interaction.
- Dependency Handling: It handles dependencies, ensuring that the
  executable file contains all the required libraries and resources.
- Platform Support: PyInstaller supports multiple platforms, allowing
  you to create executables for different operating systems.

**auto-py-to-exe:**

- Features: auto-py-to-exe is a graphical user interface (GUI) tool
  that simplifies the process of converting Python scripts to
  executables.
- User-Friendly: It's designed to be user-friendly, especially for
  those who are not familiar with command-line interfaces or packaging
  concepts.
- GUI Interface: auto-py-to-exe provides a visual interface where users
  can configure options, select script files, and adjust settings
  without using the command line.
- Simplified Configuration: It provides predefined settings and
  profiles, making it easier to create executable files without delving
  into complex configuration.
- Simpler Projects: auto-py-to-exe might be better suited for simpler
  projects with straightforward requirements, where customization is
  not a primary concern.
- Dependency Handling: Like PyInstaller, auto-py-to-exe handles
  dependencies and bundles them with the executable file.
- Platform Support: While originally developed for Windows,
  auto-py-to-exe might not offer the same level of cross-platform
  compatibility as PyInstaller.

In summary, the main difference lies in their complexity and approach to packaging Python scripts. PyInstaller offers more control and customization through the command-line interface, making it suitable for complex projects. On the other hand, auto-py-to-exe provides a simpler, GUI-based solution, ideal for users seeking a more user-friendly and streamlined approach for creating standalone executables from Python scripts. The choice between the two depends on your project's complexity, your familiarity with command-line tools, and your preference for a GUI-based interface.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, `auto-py-to-exe` is using `PyInstaller` or doesn't it? You can see in [this screenshot](https://warehouse-camo.ingress.us-east-2.pypi.io/eb29c9774b11dab42fbee0e2c5e9cf2af72895fc/68747470733a2f2f6e6974726174696e652e6e65742f706f7374732f6175746f2d70792d746f2d6578652f666561747572652e706e67) (from the official homepage) that it just executes a `pyinstaller` command. So why do the outputs differ, if I just run this command directly in my terminal?

Comment: Oh no, we've reached the point of copy-paste chatGPT answers in SO...